# How to do real time mobile opt-in in marketing cloud integrated with sales cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

We're capturing User information through web based form and the same is integrated with sales cloud which automatically creates a lead based on information provided. We've marketing cloud integrated only with sales cloud.

Now, I want to send a confirmation sms to user in real time as soon as a lead is created, and for that I need to do mobile opt-in in real time in marketing cloud.

Journey I'm planning for this would be a trigger base journey, i.e. as soon as a new lead is created, that lead contact would enter into the journey. Existing journey builder doesn't provide any option to trigger a mobile opt-in or data import activity into mobile contact list.

1. How to do real time opt-in in marketing cloud ?
2. Can I also do it in sales cloud ? Is there any option available where I can do mobile opt-in in sales cloud and marketing cloud then automatically adds into mobile contact list.

Answer (score 0):

There is no configuration between Sales Cloud and Marketing Cloud when it comes to MobileConnect Keyword subscriptions or Status settings.

That being said, Journey Builder does actually allow you to subscribe a Contact to a new MobileConnect keyword and send immediately an SMS to the Contact.

Assuming you have MobileConnect properly set up with your numbers and keywords and have the permission to Contact the client, all you really need to do is create the Journey based on Salesforce Data and configure an SMS event in this Journey.

While configuring the SMS event you select the option `Subscribe all Contacts to a Keyword` and pick the MobileConnect keyword they will be subscribed to.

Once a Contact in the Journey reaches this step, they will be created in MobileConnect with Active status and have a Opt-In status for the selected Keyword.

- [**Configure Journey Builder for Sending Messages**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_in_journeybuilder.htm&type=5)

Comment: Tried this method but didn't work.

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: One thing, I don't have country code included in mobile number. Is there any way to create an automation to do mobile opt-in on the fly i.e. as soon as a new object (Lead) is created, automation should get triggered to do mobile opt-in for particular mobile number.

Comment: Country code must always be included! And also if you are using some custom created Data Extension, make sure the field type is correct. 
The automation you ask about is possible yes, this is how it usually was done prior to the Journey Builder opt-in method.